# Click Through a <Canvas/> Element but detect hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I'm overlaying my page with a canvas element and a hover on this element triggers a function, however underneath the canvas there are objects that should be clicked. How could I make it so that the canvas still detects the hover events and continues it's mouseMove function but lets the user to interact with the stuff underneath it?

I've researched and tried the CSS property pointer-events: none, and found that you can asign pointer-events: none to parents and pointerEvents: auto to children in order to solve this problem, however, as i understand you cannot wrap the canvas element to be a parent of underlying divs, so would anyone know a way to solve it?

Basically the canvas element is used to create an interactive heatmap as the users use the website, but i need to be able to generate this heatmap and access the content underneath it

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

Here you have a `div.container` equal in size to `canvas`. Now hovering over `div.container` is the same as hovering over `canvas`. And there is another `div` for whatever clickable content you want.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  bpx-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <div>Other content for clicks</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew,  I've tried it and it doesn't work as the pointer-events has to be active for my <canvas>  element, as it's using a library that can only draw when the hover is done over the canvas